# Ruby creating arrays based on a variable number of arguments passed to a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a method that I would like to pass in a number of arguments for and then create a number of arrays based on how many arguments are passed in.

```
def method(*args)
  number_of_arrays = args.count
  for i in 1..number_of_args
    # create arrays
  end
  args.map do |arg|
      # do something and add to an array
  end
  # I should now have a number of different arrays based on how many arguments are passed in
  # do something with those arrays
end
```

Any guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def method(*args)
  arrays = Array.new(args.count) { [] }

  args.each_with_index do |arg, index|
      arrays[index] << # add some form of the arg to each array
  end
end
```